# Python 2.7: Select specific character from string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to select a specific character from a string. I know you can use the `[0:0]` and `[0:-0]` syntax etc... However I'm trying to do something different.

If a user enters `"Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]"`
or enters `"[[[[]]][[][][]"`

I'm trying to count how many square brackets have been typed and either left or right.

Thanks a lot guys for the instant response, a lot of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.count` method if you only need to count them:

```
>>>s = "Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]"
>>>s.count('[') + s.count(']')
8
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there have a better way, but it will do:

```
input = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]'
print len(re.findall("\[|\]", input))
```